# Cannot found installed ObjectAid plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, installation, objectaid

I'm using Eclipse Standard/SDK

Version: Kepler Release
Build id: 20130614-0229

I've tried to install latest GEF, ObjectAid. I'm runnning JDK 1.7.0.25
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSuVU.jpg

So, what is missing here? I cannot found the ObjectAid option
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBU9K.png

Answer (score 0):

The first image shows `Object Aid` plug-in was installed.

In your eclipse go to **Help->Help Contents** and check the help topic for `Object Aid`. Here you will find how to use `Object Aid`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i cannot find the help topic for ObjectAid

Comment: When `Object Aid` is installed from `http://www.objectaid.net/update` help is installed automatically. Are you referring this update site only?

Comment: Yes. I also tried to install it from .zip. But i cannot find the help topic

Comment: Use update site instead of zip file, so you will get latest update of this plug-in.Here you will find instructions to install this plug-in from update site. `http://www.objectaid.com/installation`

Comment: Share the user guides here http://www.filedropper.com/objectaiduserguides please refer.

Comment: Thanks. But, i just uninstalled the Eclipse. Thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 0):

ObjectAid Plugin can be installed from the below link - steps to be followed included.
[enter link description here](https://www.objectaid.com/install-objectaid)
Note : use http://www.objectaid.com/update/current as most people mention to use http://www.objectaid.com/update instead which will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link from the Object Aid website to add the component. It is not there by default
https://www.objectaid.com/install-objectaid